# How to paste clipboard data to text editor in android automatically?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a background service app which is getting data from clipboard of android. I want to paste that data to another app's focused Edittext automatically or to notes app of android OS.

Comment: "I have a background service app which is getting data from clipboard of android" -- note that [this is not possible on Android 10+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#clipboard-data). "I want to paste that data to another app's focused Edittext automatically" -- that is not possible, except perhaps through accessibility APIs, and that might restrict your ability to distribute the app. "or to notes app of android OS" -- the Android OS itself does not have a notes app. Some devices might ship with one, but that is not standard and will not exist on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

import this library.

```
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
```

This code in and listener
or in a TextWatcher in EditText

```
 ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
    ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Text");
    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
```